# Как сделать чудо линию и тень только по углам?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Заранее всем спасибо, буду должен...

Comment: Вторая линия это <hr>

Comment: всё,разобрался....думал нельзя класс присвоить hr))

Answer (score 3):

[How to create slick effects with CSS3 box-shadow](http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow).

Comment: http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/overclock-site/boxshadow-slick-effects.html
тоже самое но по русски

Comment: Я думаю что ответ таки принять нужно. Опорную точку, с чего начать поиск решения вам дали.

Comment: да,безусловно...

Comment: осталось только линию узнать как сделать